# Pictures and videos in a tableview for each user

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

My app will have a tableview with a picture and a title on each row, when the user taps it, it will open another view with that title, some texts and some pictures.

Now, I want each user to have different items in the tableview. For making it easier, suppose it is going to be a todo list like this:

1. Wash the car (Picture1) (video1) (InstructionsText)
2. Go to the groceries store (Pic2) (Vid2) (instrText2)
3. Pay the Bills (Pic3) (Vid3) (instrText3).

Now, I want to assign these items differently for each user, and show in a tableview.

USER 1 TABLE VIEW

1. Wash the car (Picture1) (video1) (InstructionsText)
2. Pay the Bills (Pic3) (Vid3) (instrText3).

USER 2 TABLE VIEW

1. Pay the Bills (Pic3) (Vid3) (instrText3).

USER 3 TABLE VIEW

1. Wash the car (Picture1) (video1) (InstructionsText)
2. Go to the groceries store (Pic2) (Vid2) (instrText2)

...

Now, here's my idea: each of these tasks should open a view controller with pictures, videos and text related to them. Using Core Data, I could create a modal, a entity called TodoList and attributes like title, text. First question: Can I create attributes for videos and pictures as well and store them here?

Suppose I have 500 different tasks, I will have to create a view controller for each, right? How would I relate these tasks to each user, like the example above? So each user would have his own tableview with the tasks leading to view controllers.

Assuming it is possible to make this work, how could I change the tasks assigned to each user directly, without having to use xcode or doing it programatically?

Comment: I suggest using one tableview with multiple sections (one for each user)? Or just custom tableviewcells for specific content? How "different" are your tasks?

Comment: Custom tableviewcells, right. Basically, I want each user to see only the tasks assigned to him and being able to access the views related only to those tasks. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use Core Data to store all your required fields in which image and video can also reside in Core Data. Use predicate to fetch the data according to constraints imposed on each user. When he will open the app, app should be able to fetch data according to user condition. After this you can load your table.

Hope this helps.

Comment: It's not properly correct to store images and videos within Core Data store. Please revisit your question.

Answer (score 0):

If we consider TO-DO apps , if a user should be able to see his own content , he will have to enter his own content through the app.This data is then stored in some backend either Core Data , SqLite or even cloud backend like Parse.com.Then the user is able to fetch his data , and see the contents in any view ...like tableView in your case.

Comment: The Todo list is just an example. I don't want the user to edit the list or the tasks. I would assign tasks for each user.

Comment: Lets say if your app receives some data , which in turn is displayed in a table view.Then naturally a user cannot edit it.But in that case every app ie every user will have the same data.To assign  specific task for each user you might need to implement some server functionality...which will send data to the app ie client according to ... his login credentials...